# PHP Curl request response 403 - not authorized

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to run a PHP curl **GET** in domain https://www.submarino.com.br.  I'm getting  403 (Forbidden). I then tried by the chrome developper to copy the curl request provided in the url and run in bash and get the same answer

My PHP code

```
public function GetStatusHost(){
    $headers   = Array();
    $headers[] = 'Host:www.submarino.com.br';
    $headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
    $headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
    $headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,pt-PT;q=0.5';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br';
    $headers[] = "If-None-Match:W/'5beff-TgqN41ZtNiOTyAH2bpA4lvYiKTE'";

    $ch        = curl_init($this->GetKeywordUrl());
    $tmp       = "/home/leilao/public_html/tmp/curl_cookie/cookie.txt";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmp);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$tmp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info      = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch); echo $info['http_code']; exit;
    return $info['http_code'];
}
```

Bash

[image]

Any ideas how to fixed this problem?

Response using header SomeHugeOAuthaccess_tokenThatIReceivedAsAString:

[image]

Comment: i can't reproduce it here, looks like you've been ip banned, this works fine for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your site (`Host:www.submarino.com.br`) use an auth credentials to provide the permission for method access.
So try to add this lines with a specific credentials:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials goes here
```

or 
    if there a `base64string` Authorization is used then you can use this also

```
$header[] = "Authorization: Bearer $access_token";
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization', 'OAuth ' . $atoken));
```

Comment: Thank you addy, I tried with my password and login but it did not work and the domain does not provide any credentials for search by api.
Any other ideas?

Comment: `$header[] = 'Authorization: OAuth SomeHugeOAuthaccess_tokenThatIReceivedAsAString';` try to add this without use of above code in my ans.

Comment: and also you can use the postman like tool for finding an exact issue.

Comment: I do not have a token authorization, I do not own any. They do not have an API for developpers, so I'm using CURL in conventional  method GET